# How do I go to the left-most position on a Turing Machine's tape?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

As far as I can tell it's not clearly defined whether a tape of the TM is infinite on both sides or just one.
For my example I am assuming that it is infinite on the right, which, if I am not wrong seems to be the most common case.

I start reading my string assuming it is on the very beginning, however, after I do some changes to my string like converting all the 0's to x's how do I come back to the very beginning? I can't just do $0, X, L$ (when you see $0$ replace with $X$ and move Left because left might be undefined and if my understanding is correct in that case the during machine Halts, as in it halts and it can't continue operation to possibly come to an accepting state.

After I travel right to left on the tape, how do I come to the beginning cell? One idea is to overwrite the initial string with blanks and then paste the string to the end so that I have a sentinel $\textbf{Blank}$ on both sides but there must be a simpler way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually, a Turing machine tape is considered infinite at both ends. To quote the notes on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#cite_note-4): Rogers 1987 (1967):13 describes "a paper tape of infinite length in both directions". Minsky 1967:118 states "The tape is regarded as infinite in both directions". Boolos Burgess and Jeffrey 2002:25 include the possibility of "there is someone stationed at each end to add extra blank squares as needed".

Comment: If your TM is really equipped with a tape bounded in at least one direction, then your definition of TM should include a definition of the behaviour in case the machine wants to walk beyond the end. A quite simple useful extension in that direction is to behave as if a specific symbol "$\infty$" is read and not move

Comment: please check this question (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/turing-machine-infinite-tape-in-one-or-two-directions)